# Fast approach to C# SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#

I'm reading data from huge csv file (5,000,000 rows and hundreds of columns) and using **SqlBulkCopy** for writing data into sql table. I'm trying to speed up performance and found **WriteToServerAsync** method in SqlBulkCopy class. It is much faster than *WriteToServer* method but cannot see any data in sql table.

```
public static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2(DataTable dtable, string sqlTableName, Int32 batch_size, string connString)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sqlTableName;

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = batch_size;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dtable);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

int batchsize = 0; 
while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
{ 
    string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t'); 
    datatable.Rows.Add(line); 
    batchsize += 1; 
    if (batchsize == flushed_batch_size) 
    { 
        InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2(dt, tabName, flushed_batch_size, connString);
        dt.Rows.Clear();
        batchsize = 0; 
    } 
    rows += 1; 
}
InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2(dt, tabName, flushed_batch_size, connString);
dt.Rows.Clear();
```

Is there anything I'm missing in my InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2 method?

Comment: Yes, an `await`. The method isn't faster, it just processes in the background. I guess it gives an error which you never catch.

Comment: Changed original bulkcopy method to public static async void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2Async and await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dtable);
Now it throws me an error: Column 'ID' does not allow DBNull.Value.

Comment: Is there any faster approach than above mentioned?

Comment: You could try using a custom implementation of an IDataReader (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anthonybloesch/2013/01/23/bulk-loading-data-with-idatareader-and-sqlbulkcopy/)).

Comment: faster, with less memory foot print approach would be reading the CSV file to stream / datareader and then pass it to sqlbulk copy. There are number of libraries out there does it for you.

Comment: Didn't see it mentioned, but you pass the DataTable to the subroutine calling SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync() - and then it returns (while the call is running async on another thread.  The first action after returning is to dt.Rows.Clear() - which is exactly what the async call is trying to work from.  The code clearly doesn't understand parallelism at all.

Answer (score 1):

My answer doesn't address your performance problems. It's to hopefully help you determine why the data isn't showing up.

Patrick mentioned the first problem in the comments. However, make sure you change the signature to include `Task` instead of `void`:

```
public static async Task InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy_2(
    DataTable dtable, string sqlTableName, Int32 batch_size, string connString)
```

Secondly, one potential reason you won't see results - or see inconsistent ones - is because you're using `Environment.Exit(0)` in your `catch` blocks.

[Environment.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) is different to a `return` statement in that it will terminate an application, and all associated threads, immediately. This could be a reason why you're not seeing any data.

Lastly, you need to decide how you want to handle the data import. Are you fine with the import process continuing if the insertion of a row throws an exception? The way you've written that nested `try..catch` gives the impression that you want it to catch an error but continue. However, the call to `Environment.Exit` effectively makes that `try..catch` redundant, so it just becomes code duplication at that point.

Comment: Just saw your latest comment, so the above is likely not that helpful. Happy to delete if need be, just let me know.